# html print a very wide page on several A4 sheets

Tags: html, printing

I have a page with a wide (say around 3000px) horizontal graph which is normally scrollable.

In the printing version I render the entire graph, (I actually have a separate JAvascript/HTML code for the printing version), so it takes lets say **three A4 widths** (landscape) on the screen.

In this situtation I see the browser (FF3 in this case) does not allow me to print the wide page on several paper sheets (based on the print preview).

**It seems like the only way to have the entire document printed is to have the user set zoom level to 30%, and then the entire graph fits on a single A4.**

I must be missing some CSS directive there, but was unable to google it anywhere.

Will appreciate pointers/ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: Thankyou, I have been convinced for some time that nobody cares how html prints

Comment: Is something like PDF an option?

Comment: I don't assume there is automatic screen-to-pdf implementation in FF3...
I might paint the pdf on the server side, which is horrible in itself.

Comment: That depends on your platform. If you have a pdf library available it is a good solution. Remember that html is designed to be able to adapt to different shaped windows. PDF is pretty good if you know the pagesize in advance. I would render the PDF from scratch, don't try to convert html->PDF

Answer (score 3):

You could add a rotation transformation to the print stylesheet. A partial solution as a long table will now be too wide...

```
.rotated-when-printed {
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(90deg);
    filter:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand',M11=6.123233995736766e-17,M12=-1,M21=1,M22=6.123233995736766e-17)
}

<!-- some very wide table -->
<table class="rotated-when-printed">
    ...
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

(a previous answer of mine to this question was deleted, don't know why: I try again)

Long time I looked for a CSS based solution on this problem, and I think it's not possible to have vertical page breaks of HTML tables through CSS (at least not page breaks on tabular data in a HTML TABLE tag, but it should be possible with tabular data organized in DIVs).

I think the only solution is to let javascript do the splitting.
When the page is loaded, javascript can check if table is wider than the page width desired: in that case it's possible to dynamically create a new table and duplicate in it only the columns that are outside the allowed width, and deleting them from original table.
All the process is a bit tricky, but results are satisfying.

It's also possible to let the javascript code run only for printing and not for the table showed on screen: a print button on the page can be arranged to run a server side code, for example php, which can generate a pdf thought the library wkhtmltopdf, passing to it the html page where is the table, *including the javascript code*. In fact wkhtmltopdf generate a pdf simulating a browser, and the javasript code will be correctly executed.

Now, this javascrpt library already exist, I wrote it and works very well (at least for my needs), and it freely available on Internet: I don't want to link it because already had a previous answer deleted, and I don't know if it was for that reason. But if someone is interested, you can ask in comments and I'll give it.

Answer (score 0):

Printing html across multiple pages like this is not a nice thing to have to do

You probably want to break the graph up into page sized chunks (e.g. a div for each page) so when they are floated beside each other the graph looks as required. Then use CSS [page-break-before](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_print_pagebb.asp) or [page-break-after](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_print_pageba.asp) to ensure that the printed pages are broken up correctly and you don't lose any content off the side of the page.

Also ensure that you have the [media](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_mediatypes.asp) type specify print for the css you use for the printable version.

Answer (score 0):

You can't control how HTML is printed in any real way - HTML/CSS/JS has no access to the print driver or browser print settings.
The only option is to convert your printable output to PDF (or some other print-centric format) and serve that instead.